# How to return multiple variables across different classes

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I am currently taking a C# class and in the class we are looking to take our error handling out of our primary code and build all the error handling and data parsing for all integers in another class, however the problem is you can only return one variable.

How can i return both a "true/false" (bool) and the parsed data from one class to another.

**Class1.cs (primary code)**

```
    int num1;

    Class2 class2Object = new Class2();

    public Class1()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    public void Num1Method()
    {
        string tempVal = "";
        bool errorFlag; //bool = true/false

        do
        {
            errorFlag = false; //no error & initialize

            Console.Write("Enter Num1: ");
            tempVal = Console.ReadLine();
            class2Object.IntErrorCheckMethod(tempVal);
        }//close do
        while (errorFlag == true);
    }//close Num1Method
```

**Class2.cs (error and parse handling)**

```
public bool IntErrorCheckMethod(string xTempVal)
    {
        int tempNum = 0;
        bool errorFlag = false;

        try
        {
            tempNum = int.Parse(xTempVal);
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            errorFlag = true;
            tempNum = 999;
        }
        return errorFlag;

    }//close int error check
```

So Class2 will only return the true/false (if there is an error or not), how can I also return the good parsed data back to Class1 to be put into the "int num1" variable?

Our professor can only think to remove the bool and use a dummy value (like if the data has an error, set the value to 999 and return it, then do an if elseif to check if the value is 999 then return an error message, otherwise submit the data to the variable.

I think its better code to be able to use a bool for the error as 999 could POSSIBLY be good data that is entered by the user.

Any ideas are appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [out parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) just like [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) methods in .NET. BTW 
instead of your method you can use

```
int tempNum;
errorFlag = Int32.TryParse(string, out tempNum);
```

Or if you really want to use your own method for parsing:

```
public bool IntErrorCheckMethod(string xTempVal, out int tempNum)
{
    tempNum = 0;
    bool errorFlag = false;

    try
    {
        tempNum = int.Parse(xTempVal);
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        errorFlag = true;
        tempNum = 999;
    }

    return errorFlag;
}
```

Usage:

```
int num1;

public void Num1Method()
{
   string tempVal;  
   do
   {
      Console.Write("Enter Num1: ");
      tempVal = Console.ReadLine();          
   }
   while(class2Object.IntErrorCheckMethod(tempVal, out num1));
}
```

---

Also consider to do some refactoring to your method:

```
public bool TryParse(string s, out int result)
{
    result = 0;

    try
    {
        result = Int32.Parse(s);
        return true; // parsing succeed
    }
    catch(FormatException)
    {
        return false; // parsing failed, you don't care of result value
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting tempNum to a dummy number, as 999 could be a good value entered by the client. if the user enters 999, would this not return as an error, even tho 999 is good int variable? Also how do i read the tempNum and errorFlag data from Class2 within Class1 and enter the values into the num1 and errorFlag within Class1.

Comment: @Meta don't set any dummy number to `tempNum` in case of exception. Just set error flag, which will notify caller that he should not look for `tempNum` value

Comment: so class 1 becomes
Console.Write("Enter Num1: ");
                    int tempNum;
                    errorFlag = class2Object.IntErrorCheckMethod(tempVal, out tempNum);

While Class2 is as shown above (must remove the int tempNum = 0; due to it being declared within the out). I am also getting an error now within Class2 "The out parameter 'tempNum' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method"

Comment: Just saw the TryParse you posted, and that gives the same error within Class2 as well. Also how is the parsed data being sent back to class1 and dumped into the num1 int variable? *keep in mind i am just starting C# and am a complete beginner)

Comment: @Meta I changed usage sample with complete implementation of your `Num1Method` method

Comment: Ahh! Very good. now the only thing to figure out is how to display an error message within the console if there is an error. Thanks a lot for the help (sorry im noob)

Comment: Also looking at the code I am somewhat confused by how exactly the good parsed data is being grabbed or how it knows where to take the good data from? is it just pulling from the variable set in the "out" in Class2 (tempNum) or is it just pulling from tempVal within Class1?

Comment: @Meta take a look on [out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx) article. It describes how value passed, and shows some samples